# WPF cutting off text on buttons after print dialog option in DevExtreme

Tags: wpf, devexpress, devextreme, devexpress-wpf

After using `PrintHelper.Print(report);` which is a function provided by namespace DevExpress.Xpf.Printing wpf does something entirely unexpected see below. It starts cutting off some button text. I mocked it up to protect the application I am working on, but you get the idea.

[image]

**Please note:** that the text does not trim off before hitting that `PrintHelper.Print(report);` function.

Here is my button code in the view

```xml
<Button Style="{StaticResource MenuButton}" 
        Command="{Binding DataContext.MenuItemCommand, 
RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" 
        CommandParameter="{Binding Title}">
    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource MenuTitleTextBlock}" 
               Text="{Binding Title}"/>
</Button>
```

I tried upgrading

```
<PackageReference Include="DevExpress.WindowsDesktop.Wpf.Printing" 
                  Version="19.2.7" />
<PackageReference Include="DevExpress.WindowsDesktop.Wpf.Reporting" 
                  Version="19.2.7-ctp" />
```

to

```
<PackageReference Include="DevExpress.WindowsDesktop.Wpf.Printing" 
                  Version="20.2.13" />
<PackageReference Include="DevExpress.WindowsDesktop.Wpf.Reporting" 
                  Version="20.2.13-ctp" />
```

Which seemed to fix my original problem of not being able to print at all. It is a bit confusing to know what caused my report not to print at all. It probably has to do with our efforts to migrate to .Net6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going through my entire WPF application and making each one have a bigger width. Some buttons also needed a bigger height and I made those changes as well. Everything seems to be working as expected now and I wish I didn't have to do it in the first place